# MongoDB (or another NoSQL) suitability to work on large dataset of items, orders, forecasts etc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mongodb, database, nosql

I'm currently working on restructuring of a database which lies under a system we have developed.  We are thinking about porting the solution to the cloud.

What we do is to retrieve large number of data from ERP systems (items, sale per day etc.) and do complicated calculations on this data per item in our own database.  The numbers of records we have for example in the sale table can be up to trillions of rows.  We create data from these calculations in the form of orders and forecasts.

I'm interested in looking at NoSQL solutions, because of suitability for cloud environment and also to simplify the codebase.  However I'm not sure on if NoSQL is suitable for use case like I have.  What do you guys think, should I stick with RDBMS or look into NoSQL?

If you think I should look closer into NoSQL, is MongoDB the way to go or is there something else you would recommend?

I'm thinking about using Node.js, Rails or Razor MVC for the code.

Comment: Data size is not enough to decide on a DB tech. You should analyze your query patterns and see if a database can support them efficiently

Answer (score 3):

If using mongodb a combination of a sharded mongodb setup and hadoop to crunch the numbers would be a good beginning. There is a very good official mongodb hadoop plugin.

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop

I would definitively load test the data setup and experiment